# Input more strings in one line

Tags: c++

I got line which looks like:
name1 - name2 (example: Josh - Marc)
I need to take those 2 names as 2 different strings.
I don't know how I could avoid this "-" while reading that line..
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Call me old fashioned but I try to write some code to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Just split the string into tokens, then get rid of any '-' tokens ... [boost tokenizer](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.tokenizer) is a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the String pattern is known then you can parse it
ex:

```
std::string s = "Josh - Marc";
std::string delimiter = "-";
std::string token = s.substr(0, s.find(delimiter));
```

Comment: Yeah I know this, but how to read it as input?
If input is "Josh - Marc" (1 line)? I cannot just use cin, because there are spaces..

Comment: Maybe you should mention in the question that you don't know how to get the input in the way you want it, if that's your problem.

Comment: @Artegor  you can read line with following `std::getline (std::cin,name);` . i advise you to use [Google](http://www.google.com) before [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

- Here is demo code.You can do it this way also,

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
     char string[20], name1[20], name2[20];
     gets(string);
     int j = 0, k = 0;
     int i = 0;
     while(string[i] != '-')
     {
       name1[i] = string[i];
       i++;
     }
     while(string[i] != '\0')
       name2[j++] = string[++i];

     cout<<name1<<" "<<name2;
   }
  ```